# Is a method which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, chat

**My Code:**

```
public ChatServer()
        {
            //create our nickname and nickname by connection variables
            nickName = new Hashtable(100);
            nickNameByConnect = new Hashtable(100);
            //create our TCPListener object
            chatServer = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(4296);
            //check to see if the server is running
            //while (true) do the commands
            while (true)
            {
                chatServer.Start();
                if (chatServer.Pending())
                {
                    Chat.Sockets.TcpClient chatConnection = chatServer.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("You Are Connected");
                    DoCommunicate com = new DoCommunicate(chatConnection);
                }
            }
        }

    public static void SendMsgToAll(string nick, string msg)
    {

        StreamWriter writer;
        ArrayList remove = new ArrayList(0);
        Chat.Sockets.TcpClient[] tcpClient = new Chat.Sockets.TcpClient[ChatServer.nickName.Count];
        ChatServer.nickName.Values.CopyTo(tcpClient, 0);
```

As from my above code, we can see that there are 2-methods i- ChatServer ii- SendMsgToAll.
So when I try to write line `Chat.Sockets.TcpClient[] tcpClient = new Chat.Sockets.TcpClient[ChatServer.nickName.Count];` in the second method

It gives the following error :

**ChatSerevr() is a method which is not valid in the given context**.

I google it but unable to find the corrrect solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: `ChatSerevr()` != `CharServer()` typo or ?

Comment: I am not clear about your comment. Can you please ellaborate.

Comment: Where is the line where the compiler throws that error?

Answer (score 3):

Either rename `ChatServer()` method, or rename `ChatServer` type (or property). Compiler thinks, that you're using a method here: `ChatServer.nickName.Count`.

Comment: The ChatServer is actually a class I believe. Then nickName is a field or a property.

Comment: @aiapatag: excuse me, my comment is for OP. :) missed nicknames.

Answer (score -1):

I may be a little bit late...

Please ensure you do not have a method with the same name as your class (the constructor does not apply of course)